# Consider the following limit: $\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\ln(1+n)-\ln(n^{2})}{\sin(1/n)}$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can someone give me some guidance on where to begin with the following limit?
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty } \frac{\ln(1+n)-\ln(n^{2})}{\sin(1/n)}
$$

Thanks!

Comment: show that the limit doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{\log(1+n)-\log n^2}{\sin\frac1n}=\overbrace{\frac1{\sin\frac1n}}^{\rightarrow\infty}\;\overbrace{\log\left(\frac1{n^2}+\frac1n\right)}^{\rightarrow-\infty}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}-\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

for $\ n\to\infty, \sin(\frac{1}{n})≈\frac{1}{n}$

and in the numerator $\ \ln(1+n)-\ln(n^2)=\ln(\frac{1}{n}+\frac{1}{n^2})$

Answer (score 0):

From the L'Hôpital's rule. You get:

$\frac{\frac{1}{n+1}-\frac{2}{n}}{\frac{-cos(1/n)}{n^2}}=\frac{\frac{n^3-2n(n+1)}{(n+1)n}}{-cos(1/n)}$

The numerator goes to $\infty$ as n $\rightarrow\infty$. And the denominator goes to $-1$ as n $\rightarrow\infty$. So the expression approaches $-\infty$ as n $\rightarrow\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

let us show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln(1 + n) - \ln(n)}{\sin(1/n)} = 1.$

we will use two facts: $\sin(small) = small + \cdots$ and $\ln(1 + small) = small + \cdots$

$\frac{\ln(1 + n) - \ln(n)}{\sin(1/n)} = \frac{\ln((1+n)/n)}{\sin{1/n}} = \frac{\ln(1+1/n)}{\sin{1/n}} = \frac{1/n + \cdots}{1/n + \cdots} = 1$ for large $n$

the limit in the question is the difference of the limits $\frac{\ln(1+n) -\ln(n)}{\sin(1/n)}$ and $\frac{\ln(n^2) - \ln(n)}{\sin(1/n)} = \frac{\ln(n)}{\sin(1/n)}.$ the limit of the second one does not exist because if you a large value for $n,$ say $1000$ you get $\frac{\ln(1000)}{\sin(1/1000} = 1000\ln(1000) = 6900+\cdots$ we have already established that the limit of the first is $1$ and the limit of the second one does not exit, therefore limit of the whole does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

- $\ln(1+n)$ is extremely close to $\ln(n)$
- $\ln(n^2)=2\ln(n)$
- So the numerator is essentially $-\ln(n)$, which goes to $-\infty$
- The denominator goes to $0^{+}$.
- So the whole expression goes to $-\infty$